# X-Editable Datepicker / Bootstrap 2 not using default date

Tags: datepicker, x-editable

This is specifically about x-editable with bootstrap 2.3.2 http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/
The x-editable selector class is 'xedit'

```
<a href="#" class="xedit" data-type="date" data-pk="1" data-clear=false data-format="dd/m/yyyy" data-viewformat="dd/m/yyyy" data-datepicker="{autoclose:0,orientation:'bottom auto',todayBtn:1,weekStart:1,endDate:'28/11/2013'}"><strong>01/01/1970</strong></a>
```

This code opens the popup datepicker OK, but it doesn't read / use the default value 01/01/1970. Using `data-value="01/01/1970"` doesn't help either, nor removing the `<strong>` tags. Once a new date is selected / set, it works fine.

Anyone experienced similar / can suggest why this doesn't work ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The `<strong>` tags do make a difference. Put them outside of your `<a>` tags. Also, update either your value `01/01/1970` to `01/1/1970` to reflect your `data-format` and `data-viewformat` or vice versa.